# Quickest way to get the value in a subquery that can return multiple rows (the value would be the same in all rows)

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS Sql query that can return 0, 1, or more rows. When there are more than one row, all the values in a particular column will be the same (due to the nature of the relationships). However, when there is more than one row, the subquery cannot be a scalar subquery, unless something is done to summarize or eliminate the additional rows.

What is the best (i.e. most efficient) way to get this column's value in a subquery?

Min and Max will do it:

```
(select max(t.mycol) from t where t.othercol = outer_reference)
(select min(t.mycol) from t where t.othercol = outer_reference)
```

but both of those require scanning all the records in the futile attempt to find a value that is larger/smaller than the one in the first record examined.

```
(select distinct t.mycol from t where t.othercol = outer_reference)
```

would also work, except there would again be a cost for SQL to do a futile search for values different from what is in the first record.

Right now I'm doing:

```
(select top 1 t.mycol from t where t.othercol = outer_reference) -- note: no ORDER BY clause
```

but the execution plan looks like it is doing a Clustered Index Scan ('mycol' is indexed) which, together with the Top operation itself, is consuming 19% of the query "cost" for what is an otherwise very complex query (i.e. it is not just 19% of nothing).

I really want it to just return the first value it finds, spending no time doing any ordering on the records.

Perhaps I'm wrong to think that the cost in the execution plan is due to trying to find all the records that match the 'where' clause; it may be that I am seeing the cost of the 'where' condition, which involves comparing a field in 't' to an outer scope reference. It should also be noted that it is the *estimated* execution plan I'm looking at.

Part of the problem is that the semantics of the situation—that t.mycol is the same in all the matching records—isn't really formally expressible in any manner that I can see.

Updated/extra information:
I actually have two such subqueries in my main query, for two different columns in the same table t. I have found that by using an OUTER APPLY the expensive search of t will only occur once per main query record and so the number of table reads is cut in half.

I added:

```
outer apply (
    select top 1 mycol, myothercol from t where t.othercol = outer_reference
) as SomeT
```

and instead of the subqueries the outer query refers to SomeT.mycol and SomeT.myothercol

Comment: Repeating what @JohnCappelletti said for both parts: we need more info on the data and schema, and that a lateral join _might_ solve this. Adding that a windowing function is another avenue to explore, and that an index change might help your `TOP 1` attempt get a better query plan (but again, we need to more about the schema to suggest any specific change).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a table-valued function to return that value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fSelectMycol (@othercol)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    select top(1) mycol from YourTable where othercol = @othercol;
GO
```

Then you can...

```
SELECT 
    y.foo,
    f.mycol
FROM YourTable y
    OUTER APPLY fSelectMycol(y.othercol) f
```

Comment: As mentioned in the additional information I've added, using outer apply of a (select top 1 ...) query to get both columns cuts in half the number of row reads because only one search occurs for both fields. However using a function as you describe seems to only add complexity (and doesn't improve the speed).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that my worry that SQL is wasting time finding more than one matching record in t is unfounded. An analysis of the IO statistics indicates that the number of reads is consistent with SQL doing a sequential scan of t and stopping at the first matching record.

The node in the execution plan which does this search is a Clustered Index Scan on the clustered primary key index for t. What this boils down to is a linear search through t to find a matching record.

I do have an explicit index on t.othercol but SQL is not using it, so I'll have to play around with query hints to see if I can get the index used. This index has no "included" columns, so once a hit is found, the result (t.mycol) will not be directly available, so SQL will then have to read the main record or the primary-key clustered index.

So, fundamentally, the answer is not that time is wasted finding or looking at more than one matching record, but that the search for matching records is itself a slow operation because of poor choice of index.

Also, using outer apply is advantageous when there is more than one such field to look up as the search on t will only occur once per main record.